# Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-requests

I installed the requests package, but when I start to use it, I got this error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

r = requests.get("http://someSite.com/path")
```

I checked some solution to this problem, and most of them saying that either there is a mistake with importing the package, or that a file with the name requests.py exist in the current directory, but it's not the case for me.

it's been a while since I got this error, and I stuck with it.

any idea? thanks.

**UPDATE**

FULL error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, ec, rsa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import RSABackend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 76, in <module>
    import parser
  File "/home/lichiheb/Desktop/parser.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get("http://t...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/search-results-jobs/?searchId=1483197031.949&action=search&page=1&view=list")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: check `print(requests.__file__)`

Comment: This what I got /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.pyc
so ?

Comment: Did you call your file `requests.py`?

Comment: file path seems ok. Show FULL error message (Traceback).

Comment: @user2357112 No, I did mention that in the question.

Comment: always put FULL error message in QUESTION - not in ideone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is called `parser.py` which conflicts with a built-in module name [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html).

The error message about `requests` was a weird and unfortunate coincidence.  Just rename your module to something else.